# Django - custom logger

Tags: django, logging

I have some interesting task - write custom logger for Django, that stores request (INFO level) and show data (DEBUG level) in file. 
I cannot use standard Django logger.

Can you point me in right direction? 
Should I use middleware?

Thanks. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far i figure out something like:

```
import os
import logging

from django.conf import settings


# logging config
logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'debug.log'),
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class FileLoggerMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        request_log = 'Path: {}, GET: {}, POST: {}'.format(
            request.path, request.GET, request.POST)
        logger.info(request_log)

        # We have queries logging out of box
        # But here what i wood wrote:
        # from django.db import connection
        # for q in connection.queries:
        #   query_log = "({}) QUERY ".format(q.time, q.sql ) //and more info
        #   logger.debug(query_log)
        return response
```